# Unable to send a ajax post javascript object to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post with ajax the javascript object to asp.net controller, but i am getting the code **500 internal server error** Here is my code

```
***JS CODE***
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PackageCtr/AjaxRequest',
            data: JSON.stringify(package),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            failure: function (response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

```
***Controller PackageCtr Code***
[HttpPost]
        public string AjaxRequest(MyPackage package)
        {
            MyPackage package = package;

            return "Success";
        }
```

I would appreciate any help on how to fix this problemen

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Bind between the C# class MyPackage and the variable JSON "package". You can isolate the problem sending null or changing your method to receive an simple string, just to test if your Controller will receive your request.

If it doesn't work, you can test other parts of your code, like URL...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I post models with ajax.

```
<script>
function PostForm() {
        var model = $('#your_package_form_id').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/PackageCtr/AjaxRequest',
            type: 'POST',
            data: model,
            success: function (data) {


            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and in your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public string AjaxRequest(MyPackage model)
        {

             return "Success";

        }
```

Hope this helps!

Note: This may be a duplicate of [How to convert formcollection to model ins ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956620/how-to-convert-formcollection-to-model-ins-asp-net-mvc)